# Django regex pattern matching

Tags: django, django-urls

I have the following urlpatterns:

```
url(r'^api/daily-means/$', views.daily_means.as_view(), name='daily_means'),
url(r'^api/daily-means/sites/(?P<url>\w+)/$', views.site_daily_means.as_view()),
url(r'^api/daily-means/pollutant/(?P<poll>\w+)$/', views.pollutant_daily_means.as_view()),
```

The first two work fine. The last one show work the same as the second one but it does not. Im not that great with regex and urlpatterns but I assume there is something with the second url pattern which is stopping the last one from running. Can anyone else see a reason for this?

Comment: Can you add the test URLs you have tried for 2nd and 3rd patterns?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by test URLs?

Comment: Yes. URLs you have tested.

Comment: Sorry i see.  For instance:  domain.com/api/daily-means/sites/cardiff  - 2nd url, works fine. Then for the third domain.com/api/daily-means/pollutant/ozone  which does not work

Comment: Your 3rd regex pattern `(?P<poll>\w+)$/` should be `(?P<poll>\w+)/$`

Comment: Well spotted! It's all working fine now, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django will append the end slash if it is not provided. In your regex, you are matching without the end slash.
`url(r'^api/daily-means/pollutant/(?P<poll>\w+)$/', views.pollutant_daily_means.as_view()),`

The following URL pattern should work(after including the end slash as a part of URL match).

`url(r'^api/daily-means/pollutant/(?P<poll>\w+)/$', views.pollutant_daily_means.as_view()),`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I didn't know that Django will append the end slash so that was useful to learn.